# Change certain values in cells automatically from other spreadsheet or sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, scripting, importrange

please consider that I am a total newbie with these things.
At work, I have an everyday plan of two numbers - money and people.
I know these numbers for a month ahead.

I have my own (another) spreadsheet with data, where I enter numbers during the day.
What I want to achieve is that the data with plans in one spreadsheet will appear the next day at a specific time, let's say 8 AM in another spreadsheet with my data in specific cells.

I know I will have to use scripts, but I don't know how they should look and how to achieve this result.
Thank you kindly in for any possible solutions.

Comment: It's a fairly simple problem.  You may use a time based trigger to run the script.  I might consider building the script in a separate container spreadsheet and construct a table on one or more of your sheets to describe the data transfers in detail so that the script can read the table and make the transfers and you can update it without making any changes to the script.

Comment: You can follow [this introduction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to get started working with Sheets and Apps Script. You'll need to access the different sheets with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)). then work with the Sheets' [ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) to get the data you want. Lastly you can use [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the tabular approach to build timers that I use for cooking different items. I make a sheet/tab for each cooking process for example rice is shown below.

[image]

When the app runs it opens up like this:

[image]

This screen allows the user to enable the audio.

[image]

This screen allows the operator to choose a timing process.

[image]

This screen runs the timer process automatically and allows to me to add additional timers if I wish.  The browswer client has to remain active during this time since this app is running on the clientside.

But your script will be running on the server and will probably have no user interace at all.  It will just create the spreadsheets and sheets and make the data transfer total autonomously when it receives the timebased trigger.  So you won't need to create any html dialogs for your script.  It will just run on the server performing the operations that you specify.  Of course, it's easier to build something like this if you already know how to program them.  So if you have no programming you may find it necessary to hire someone to assist you in the development.